# Can I access an elements index within a dictionary value?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, templatetags

I am passing a dictionary with one Key, Value pair where the value is a list of images. Is there any way to only loop through the first 4 elements within the values list?

Here is my views.py file:

```
def portfolio_couples(request):
    img_list = os.listdir("/Users/andershanson/Documents/Django/kh_photo/static/my_app/images/portfolio")
    context = {"images": img_list}
    return render(request, 'my_app/couples.html', context)
```

Here is my HTML template:

```html
{% if images %}
    {% for image in images %}
        <img src="/static/my_app/images/portfolio/{{ image }}" class="container-fluid px-0 m-0" alt="portfolio-pic">
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This currently works looping through images, but is there any way to index the the first 4 elements in the dictionary value?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can slice this in the view:

```
def portfolio_couples(request):
    img_list = os.listdir("/Users/andershanson/Documents/Django/kh_photo/static/my_app/images/portfolio")
    #                    slicing ↓  ↓
    context = {"images": img_list[:4]}
    return render(request, 'my_app/couples.html', context)
```

or with the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for image in images|slice:":4" %}
    <img src="/static/my_app/images/portfolio/{{ image }}" class="container-fluid px-0 m-0" alt="portfolio-pic">
{% endfor %}
```

But likely the view is the best place to do this, since the view is responsible for the *business logic*, whereas a template is responsible for the *rendering* logic.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Any way I can do it within the template tag??

Comment: @ahanson: yes, although I do not recommend doing this in the template.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your wisdom